# Network Drive with WINS server

Tags: networking, hard-drive, cloud-storage, wins-server

I'm looking for a network drive with Windows Internet Name Service (WINS) server.

We're trying to support a software which uses WINS to connect to the server and store every data on that same computer/server.

Is there such a thing as network drive with WINS server (cloud drive with WINS). I'm trying to look for it all over the Internet and could not find one specifically supporting such protocol.